# Не отцентрирована иконка загрузки картинки

Tags: дефект, дизайн, загрузка-изображения

Когда нажимаешь на кнопку загрузки изображения, открывается поле для загрузки, а кнопка подсвечивается. Вот эта подсвеченная кнопка явно расположена криво.

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Не так явно, как для гиперссылки. Но вообще, как-то уже пофигу на такие мелочи стало :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я ссылки кнопкой не вставляю)